# How to extract a subset of variable arguments (like `int ... x`) for a recursion function?

Tags: java, recursion, arguments, variadic-functions

I am learning the vararg argument method in Java but I have no idea how to subset the variable arguments if I want to create a recursion function.

---

For example, I attempted to build a function `max`, which aims to obtain the max value from variable arguments, e.g., `fmax(1,5,3,2,7,-2)`, but I wanted it in a recursion manner, i.e., `fmax(1,5,3,2,7,-2) = Math.max(fmax(1,5,3,2,7,-2), -2)`, so on so forth till the recursion ends when meeting the termination condition.

My piece of code is as below

```
    public static int fmax(int... x) {
        if (x.length == 1) {
            return x[0];
        }
        return Math.max(fmax(XXXXXXX), x[x.length-1]);
    }
```

but I have no clue what should be filled in for the part `XXXXXXX`, which actually should be a subset of `x` (excluding the last entry of `x`).

### Question

Is there any way to get `x[0], x[1], ..., x[x.length-2]` to replace `XXXXXXX`? Or, do we have some workaround? Much appreciated!

Comment: The same way that you would if you got an array by any other means - because you **did** get an array, and the means doesn't matter.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Do you mean we can use `Arrays.copyOfRange(x,0,x.length-1)`?

Comment: Almost. Please read the documentation, and think carefully about the necessary endpoints of the slice.

Comment: Okay, I see, the endpoint is exclusive. Thanks for the thread, which solves my problem!

Comment: "Is there any way to get x[0], x[1], ..., x[x.length-2]" that would require creating *separate* array with reduced size. But that means you would need to populate such array each time you call your method. This means you would need to copy `N-1` first time, `N-2` elements in another recursive call, N-3, etc. so you introduce O(N^2) complexity. Instead of varags you could accept `int[]` array and additional argument which represents current "limit" of array (which actually be position of element *currently tested*).

Comment: @Pshemo Really good point! Thanks! I am just wondering about the "possibility" of using varargs in recursions all the time (regardless of the complexity, though) :P